# How to output a String with JRecord

Tags: java, xml, flat-file, jrecord

I am trying to convert a XML/Bean (either one) to a fixed length flatfile with JRecord. I am not able to output it correctly to a String in file. I can only get an output as binary.
So I will just convert a XML/Beant to String. Not to a Binary Fixed Length and so on.

Any chance of someone who have solved this issue with JRecord?

Any other Framework with example´you can reccomend? And with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [JRecordBind](http://jrecordbind.org/), a Java library that does the same as JRecord (I think) and that it's based on XML Schema

The are a couple of examples on the homepage, while more are available as input for the tests

https://github.com/ffissore/jrecordbind/tree/master/jrecordbind-test/src/test/resources